# What type of method to use for injecting script into page on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have a chrome extension that injects some javascript into the current tab when the popup.html page is opened in the extension. I'm trying to make the extension inject the code when the page is loaded, and I'm not sure what path to take.

However, chrome is giving me these errors when I try to run background.js on the background page:

[image: error1]
and

[image: error2]

I don't know how to resolve these errors. They seem to be related to permission errors not allowing me to run chrome.tabs.executeScript through the background page. I wasn't aware that the background page didn't have access to all urls, or am I mistaken in interpreting this error message? My manifest file:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/inject.js", "js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "<all_urls>"

  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "js/inject.js"]
      }
    ],
```

**Edit: background code:**

```
function cssInject(){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '$("*").css("font-family", "Courier", "important"); $("*").css("font-size", "18pt", "important"); $("*").css("background-color", "#fbfbfb", "important"); $("*").css("line-height", "1.5", "important")'
  });
}
function cssRemove(){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '$("*").css("font-family", ""); $("*").css("font-size", ""); $("*").css("background-color", ""); $("*").css("line-height", "")'
  });
}
```

Comment: I kind of recognise this error. You need to include your background code that injects the script to diagnose further. NOT as an image.

Comment: Thanks, added. cssInject and cssRemove are in inject.js and one is called at the end of background.js depending on the value of a variable. I can include the rest of the code if it's needed, but I wasn't sure if it'd be too distracting/irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because `chrome.tabs.executeScript` without the tab ID argument tries to inject the code in the *current active tab*.

Your error indicates that you had an (undocked) Dev Tools window open and focused when that code executed. It counts as the active tab.

You need to be focused on the tab you want to inject the code to for it to work. Docking your Dev Tools will help with that.

Comment: Thanks, but if I reload extension by through the chrome://extensions page after closing dev tools, it gives me the same error. Could this be because I also have the chrome dev editor open (though not focused)?

Comment: Another script, background.js, calls functions.

Comment: Whenever that code is triggered, it applies to the currently focused tab, unless you supply a tab ID. I guess the real question is how to call it. If it's some tab-related event, you need to pass the ID.

Comment: Hm. I think the problem might be with the version of chrome that I'm using. If I save my code and reload the unpacked extension in my current version of chrome, then there will be no errors except for "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in the console of the current tab. However, chrome canary (which I was using to test the code with all other extensions disabled) gives me multiple errors. I included "chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code:"alert('hello');" });" before I called cssInject, and the alert only showed up on the current release of chrome.